# Not having clarity that what author is saying.

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

The set of all points such that $\pi/2 < \operatorname{Arg} (z-2-3\iota)< \pi$. How to find those points who satisfy this inequality?

Comment: Welcome to Maths SX! What's $\iota$ (iota)?

Comment: I am not understanding what you are asking ?

Comment: Neither we do..

Comment: I am asking what this inequality means?

Comment: Your initial post mentioned `iota` (which I converted to the Greek letter $\iota$).. What is it supposed to be?

Comment: $\iota$ is (in some fields of engineering) used for $\sqrt{-1}$.

Comment: @Bernard yes this is supposed as euler's iota. Sqrt (-1)

Comment: It seems Euler used $i$ not $\iota$.  But some people do use $\iota$.  See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Imaginary_unit#Alternative_notations

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I expect that your "$\iota$" is just "i" the imaginary unit.

Write the complex number z as a+ bi.  Then z- 2- 3i= (a- 2)+ (b- 3)i.  We can write that in "polar form", $re^{i\theta}$ with $r= \sqrt{(a-2)^2+ (b- 3)^2}$ and "argument" $\theta= \arctan\left(\frac{b-3}{a- 3}\right)$.  Saying that $\pi/2< \operatorname{Arg}(x- 2- 3i)< \pi$ is saying that $\pi/2< \arctan\left(\frac{b-3}{a- 3}\right)< \pi$, in the second quadrant.

Comment: Thanks. But could you please gave me some geometrical perspective of it?

Answer (score 0):

The numbers with argument $\pi$ are the negative reals.  So one boundary of your region is the set of $z$ with
$$
(z-2-3i) = -t, \quad t>0
\\
z = -t+2+3i,\quad t>0
$$
which is a half line: staring at the point $2+3i$ with direction $-1$.

The numbers with argument $\pi/2$ are the imaginary axis above the origin.  So the other boundary of your region is the set of $z$ with
$$
(z-2-3i) = it,\quad t>0
\\
z = it+2+3i
$$
which is again a half line: staring at the point $2+3i$ with direction $i$.

Your complete region is a sector with vertex 2+3i, and edges extending up and left from there.

Comment: What do you mean by direction -1 and what if I replace pie/6 instead of pie/2.

Answer (score 0):

Geometrically, it is the open second quadrant translated at the point with affix $2+3i$.